# Android app, tablet only on google play. How?

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, google-play, tablet

I have just made an android application using PhoneGap which was designed for use with only tablets. However, after uploading the app to google play, it says it is only available for phones and cannot be installed on tablets :/

How can I make it so that the application is only available for tablets?

This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.p4l.inhome" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
             android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
             android:screenOrientation="landscape"
             android:name="InHomeFinal" android:label="Pay4Later InHome"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to change the suppport-screens to:<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

Comment: also check whether your require all the permissions bcoz google play filter the app based on permission

Comment: This will be useful to you: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Answer (score 1):

Change in manifest like this :

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

This will prevent any small/mobile device to install your application. Only device with large screen will have the privilege to install your application. Play store will automatically select the devices cording to these settings.

Comment: Ok i will do that. How come it defaulted to only phones though? surely it would have chose phones and tablets?

Comment: For large tablets minimum SDK version starts at 13. Google suggests you set it to 14 for tablets.